# return callback in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a callback as one of the parameters of this function, on the `callback(false)` line it that `Type 'Void' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanLiteralConvertible'`. Why? My callback should return a `Bool`, which false definitely is

```
func facebookLoginWithCallback(callback: ((Void) -> (Bool))) -> Void {
    let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, block: {(user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> (Void) in
        if (user == nil) {
            println(error)
            callback(false)
        } else if ((user?.isNew) == true) {

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: "callback" takes no parameter, you are passing in boolean "callback(false)". Thats the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to return bool value, then use following code

```
    func facebookLoginWithCallback(callback: (Bool) -> Void) {
    let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, block: {(user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> (Void) in
        if (user == nil) {
            println(error)
            callback(false)
        } else if ((user?.isNew) == true) {

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your callback does return a `Bool`, but it takes no arguments (i.e. `Void`).

You invoke it with argument `false` which can't be converted to `Void` hence the error message.

You can change the callback type to `Bool -> Void` so it takes a `Bool` and does not return value.